# OPC DA Client - Unable to assign item.Value to VBA variable

Tags: excel, vba, opc

Below is an OPC Client written in VBA. It is using the OPC Foundation DA libraries. I am able to get the current value of the item (I can read it in locals window), but it is not assigning the value to `myValue = theItem.Value` Hovering over `theItem.Value` during a break shows the value as well.

Any thoughts?

```
Public Sub ReadValue()
    Dim serverNames As Variant
    Dim listServers As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim theStates As Variant

    Set theServer = New OPCServer
    serverNames = theServer.GetOPCServers
    theStates = Array("Disconnected", "Running", "Failed", "No Configuration", "Suspended", "In Test")
    For i = LBound(serverNames) To UBound(serverNames)
        Debug.Print (serverNames(i))
    Next i
    
    theServer.Connect ("MyOPCServer")
    Debug.Print theServer.VendorInfo
    Debug.Print theServer.MajorVersion & "." & theServer.MinorVersion
    Debug.Print theStates(theServer.ServerState)
    Debug.Print theServer.StartTime
    Debug.Print theServer.CurrentTime
    Debug.Print theServer.LastUpdateTime

    
    
    'Groups
        Dim theGroup As OPCGroup
        Dim theGroups As OPCGroups
        If theGroups Is Nothing Then
            Set theGroups = theServer.OPCGroups
        End If
        If theGroup Is Nothing Then
            Set theGroup = theGroups.Add("testing")
            txtName = theGroup.name
        End If
    
        theGroup.UpdateRate = CLng(1000)
        theGroup.DeadBand = CLng(1)
        theGroup.TimeBias = CLng(0)
        theGroup.IsActive = CBool(1)
        theGroup.IsSubscribed = CBool(1)
        
        
'
    Dim theItem As OPCItem
    Dim theItem1 As OPCItem
    Dim myItems As Variant
    Dim myValue As Variant
    Dim myWriteValues As Variant
    Dim handles(1) As Long
    Dim Errors() As Long
    Dim CancelID As Long
    Dim TransID As Long
    
    myItems = Array("MyPathBlahBlahBlah.CV")
    myWriteValues = Array(8, 0, 1)
    
    For i = LBound(myItems) To UBound(myItems)
        Set theItem = theGroup.OPCItems.AddItem(myItems(i), currentHandle)
        myValue = theItem.Value
        handles(1) = theGroup.OPCItems.Item(1).ServerHandle
        theGroup.OPCItems.Remove 1, handles, Errors

    Next i

   theServer.Disconnect
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After review/trouble shooting.

The OPCItem object provides methods to read the current value of the item in the server and write a new value to the item. I have included these facilities into this dialog. The read method provided on an OPCItem object performs a synchronous read from the server and can be configured to read either from cache or from the device. To read from cache both the group and item should be active, but synchronous read operations directly from the device do not depend on the active state of either the group or item.

Adding the following code allowed me to assign to variable.

```
Dim source As OPCDataSource
Dim myValue As Variant
source = OPCDevice
theItem.Read source, myValue
```